# Why does asksaveasfilename not return the file type?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, openfiledialog, filedialog

Tkinter is a great package and filedialog has some very helpful features. Both askopenfilename and asksaveasfilename have the 'filetypes' attribute, but it works differently for each one.

With askopenfilename it provides options in the GUI and returns the filetype, BUT

with asksaveasfilename it only provides options in the GUI and does not return the filetype. Example code is shown below:

```
import tkinter as tk 
from tkinter import filedialog 


old_file_name = filedialog.askopenfilename(title = "Choose file",filetypes=\
                                       (('All files','*.*'),\
                                        ('tagData','*.tagData'),\
                                        ('FDAX files','*.fdax'),\
                                        ('CSV files','*.csv')))

new_file_name = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(initialdir = "/",filetypes=\
                                         (('tagData','*.tagData'),\
                                          ('FDAX files','*.fdax'),\
                                          ('CSV files','*.csv'),\
                                          ('XLS files','*.xls')))

print(old_file_name)
print(new_file_name)
```

Output:

```
 C:/Users/christian.abbott/Desktop/FDAX_Error/example.csv
 C:/Users/christian.abbott/Desktop/example
```

I have looked for good filedialog documentation but have not been able to find it. Why does the package behave this way? Is there a better option to extract the full path of a user-prompted file path?

Comment: How did you select `example` in the second case? Did you type `example` into the dialog, or did you double-click on the option in the GUI?

Comment: My tests all give the extension when using `filedialog.asksaveasfilename`.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem with Python 3 on Windows 10. I managed to solve it by removing the * before the period in the file types tuples. The following change should, hopefully, do what you want:

```
  new_file_name = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(initialdir = "/",filetypes=\
                                     (('tagData','.tagData'),\
                                      ('FDAX files','.fdax'),\
                                      ('CSV files','.csv'),\
                                      ('XLS files','.xls')))
```

This worked for me, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with tkinter. Windows file explorer hides the file extensions from you by default. So when you see a "example" file in file explorer, Windows is lying to you. The *actual* filename is "example.csv". Most programs (including python) do not lie, and show you the actual filename.

For entering the filename tkinter uses the OS file selection widget and just displays whatever it returns. I tested it with Win7 and it did not include the extension; however in Debian Jessie it did. If it does not you can always add some code to do it for the user:

```
if not new_file_name.endswith(('tagData','fdax','csv','xls')):
    new_file_name += '.csv'
```

Search in the start menu for "show extensions" and you can turn this "feature" off.

Comment: This doesn't match my tests; in my tests, tkinter will include the extension automatically.

Comment: @user2357112 Hmm interesting. It seems to depend on the OS (I guess that makes sense). I tested OPs code with python 3.6, tcl 8.6 and did not get the extension included. However in Linux, python 3.4, tcl 8.6 it did.

Comment: I am not worried about seeing the file extensions, but worried about what python returns. Python returns a full path (including extension) with askopenfilename, but does not include the extension with asksaveasfilename even though the file extension is selected in the GUI drop down. I am running Windows 7.